# Google Cloud Storage Resumable Upload - Is uploadid Resumable

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am trying to figure out which is better: resumable upload or signed url. For upload only. Does anyone know if one uploadid can be used by multiple uploads? Or how can a user upload multiple files using one uploadid?

Comment: You can only upload one file per resumable upload ID. Can you please provide a bit more detail about what you're trying to accomplish? Resumable uploads and signed URLs are useful for different situations (former for being able to restart uploads that get interrupted partway through, the latter for granting access to users who don't have a Google acct).

Comment: I was trying to give access to users without google account. You already answered my question. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to allow users without Google credentials to upload objects, signed URLs are your best bet. This is their intended purpose.

You *can* use uploadIds to accomplish the same goal, but they are much less featureful in this regard. For example, they do not support setting expiration times, and the server must set all parameters other than the data itself.